# CsvHelper: treat multiple consecutive tabs as one

Tags: tabs, csvhelper

I'd like to use CsvHelper to manage tab delimited file.
I'm running into the case where I find multiple consecutive tabs that must be treated as a single tab. By default CsvHelper treats every tab as a single delimiter.

It is possibile to configure it as I need? If yes, could you please tell me how?
Thanks

Comment: Can you share some extra details about your problem?  Is the issue that the CSV file is missing a field for that specific row, or is the issue that multiple tabs are used **consistently** as a delimiter, or is the issue that your CSV files are inconsistent and sometimes extra delimiters are just thrown in?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do it if there is not a consistent number of tabs between each field.  It would work if you had say exactly 3 tabs between each field.

Comment: Rewrite the file prior to opening with csvhelper, use regex: `Regex.Replace(node.InnerText, @"\t{2,}", @"\t");` to replace multiple tabs with a single tab.